# ENOTFOUND Package –save not found

Tags: bower-install

On running this command `bower install –save polymer` I get the following output.

```
bower polymer#*                 cached https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#1.6.1
bower polymer#*               validate 1.6.1 against https://github.com/Polymer/polymer.git#*
bower                        ENOTFOUND Package –save not found
```

What can the issue be? I'm running this on OS X 10.11.

Comment: use : bower install polymer --save

Answer (score -1):

Its not `-save`. it should be `--save`